# how to check for a missing attribute?

Tags: python, class, oop, reflection, attributes

I have to check if `foo` is a attribute of `myclass`.

Right now I do

```
def myclass():
    try:
        self.foo
    except AttributeError:
        self.foo = 'default'
```

while I think I should be doing

```
if not hasattr(self,'foo'):
    self.foo = 'default'
```

Is there any difference between the two approaches, and which one should be preferred?

I am looking for the following criteria:

- Consistency with multiple inheritance
- Portability across python versions
- Limited overhead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both of those approaches are functionally equivalent.

From [the `hasattr` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hasattr):

> **hasattr(object, name)**
>
> The arguments are an object and a string. The result is True if the string is the name of one of the object’s attributes, False if
>   not. **(This is implemented by calling getattr(object, name) and seeing
>   whether it raises an AttributeError or not.)**

And [the `getattr` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) state the following:

> `getattr(x, 'foobar')` is equivalent to `x.foobar`

---

Regarding speed, my tests show that `hasattr` is a little faster. The results with 1 million iterations were:

```
hasattr: 0.6325701880014094 seconds
try:     0.8206841319988598 seconds
```

Unless you're writing highly optimized code, there's no need to worry about such a small difference. There's also no need to worry about compatibility with python versions; attribute access and `hasattr` are available in every version of python.

---

In the end, it comes down to preference. Choose whichever you find more readable.